# xcode 3.2 - setting user header search paths in IDE

Tags: xcode

I'm having trouble adding header search paths to Xcode 3.2, using the IDE. When I click on the project in the files list on the left, then click 'info', then click the 'build' tab, there is no field to enter in search paths. But I've seen this field in other people's screenshots.

Here's a screenshot of the 'build' tab that I get: http://tinypic.com/r/28a4z2x/5

Why doesn't the 'Header search path' field appear for me?

Comment: Question - why are you using a version of Xcode that has been obsolete for several years? You are wasting your time using such old tools.

Comment: rmaddy - I have no choice. I'm developing a plug-in for Acrobat and the latest version of Xcode it supports is 3.2.